# What is meant by "monotonic reset"?

Tags: reset, push-pull, open-drain

Can someone tell me what does it mean by Monotonic Reset? I read this below paragraph from [this document](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/LAN8710A%20QFN%20Rev%20G%20Schematic%20Checklist.pdf) and got this doubt.

> A reset generator / voltage monitor is one option to provide a proper reset. Better yet, for increased design flexibility, a controllable reset (GPIO, dedicated reset output) should be considered. In this case, SMSC recommends a push-pull type output (not an open-drain type) for the monotonic reset to ensure a sharp rise time transition from low-to-high"

Comment: Newbie - Hi, I've added a link to what I believe is the source of the text you quoted. If your source document was actually a different one, please edit the link I added. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Monotonic means the same as in mathematics. Basically the derivative of a signal must not change sign, and as an extreme case a signal can still be considered monotonic even if derivative goes to zero.

When the signal is changing to some direction, like reset pin voltage having a rising edge where the voltage is going from low to high, the signal voltage is only allowed to increase (or stay same which means it stopped increasing), but the voltage is not allowed to decrease at all even momentarily during the rising edge.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Just a short question: Isn't all reset or signal change, the same monotonic right? If it rises, it will rise to maximum and settle right? It will not decrease unless there is some other trigger event?

Comment: Not necessarily. That’s why they mention monotonic. Strange things can happen on power up.